# Get the error 405 (Method Not Allowed) when trying to submit a form using AJAX and PHPMailer

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, phpmailer, http-status-code-405

I'm trying to create an application form using AJAX and PHPMailer, but I get the 405 error(Not allowed). I get an alert 'An error has occurred' which means that **response.ok** is *false*. As far as I understand the server knows the request method but for some reason I can't get a response. Where can be the issue and how to solve it?
Thank you in advance!
This is the formSend function in my JS file:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   const form = document.getElementById('form')
   const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper')
   form.addEventListener('submit', formSend)

   async function formSend(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
   
      let error = formValidate(form)
      let formData = new FormData(form)

      if (error === 0) {
         form.classList.add('_sending')
         wrapper.classList.add('_sending')
         let response = await fetch('sendmail.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
         })
         if (response.ok) {
            let result = await response.json()
            alert(result.message)
            form.reset()
            form.classList.remove('_sending')
            wrapper.classList.remove('_sending')
         } else {
            console.log(response.status)
            alert('An error has occurred')
            form.classList.remove('_sending')
            wrapper.classList.remove('_sending')
         }
      } else {
         alert('Check all inputs and try again')
      }
   }
```

And sendmail.php:

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->setLanguage('uk', 'phpmailer/language/');
$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->setFrom('info@fls.guru', 'форма заявки');
$mail->addAddress('kenici780@gmail.com');
$mail->Subject = 'Новая заявка!';

$body = '<h1>Новая заявка!</h1>';

if (trim(!empty($_POST['name']))){
   $body.= '<p>Имя: '.$_POST['name'].'</p>';
}
if (trim(!empty($_POST['surename']))){
   $body.= '<p>Фамилия: '.$_POST['surename'].'</p>';
}
if (trim(!empty($_POST['email']))){
   $body.= '<p>Email: '.$_POST['email'].'</p>';
}
if (trim(!empty($_POST['lesson']))){
   $body.= '<p>Название кружка / секции: '.$_POST['lesson'].'</p>';
}
if (trim(!empty($_POST['address']))){
   $body.= '<p>Адрес: '.$_POST['address'].'</p>';
}
if (trim(!empty($_POST['phone']))){
   $body.= '<p>Телефон: '.$_POST['phone'].'</p>';
}

$mail->Body = $body;

if (!$mail->send()) {
   $message = 'Ошибка отправки формы';
} else {
   $message = 'Заявка отправлена';
}

$response = ['message' => $message];

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: You **are** getting a response, the response says "You aren't allowed to make a request with the POST method to this URL". What HTTP server are you using? Have you checked it supports PHP? And is configured to allow PHP?

Comment: At a guess you're serving this content from the filesystem, or using some test server in an IDE which only supports simple static sites

Comment: I get this error using my filesystem. I have also uploaded it to a server but there I get a plain 500 error ('Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()')

Comment: If you get a 500, the details will be in the web server's error log.

Comment: I only get this "sendmail.php:1     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()"

Comment: Why not just use a local webserver? Easier to test it there. But yeah if you get a 500, either enable php error reporting, or check the php error log file on the server. If nothing there, check the apache log. A 500 could mean almost anything, we can't help without the specific error message

Comment: long before you get to write javascript code, you need to write a unit test on php side to prove you can actually send an email using phpmailer. Study phpunit first then write a single test proving you can actually send an email. You will probably find most of the errors you got there first.

Comment: _"I only get this"_ - that is clearly still from somewhere on the client side. You need to go and check the actual error log on the server.